# SharePoin 2013 Site Deletion from IIS

Tags: sharepoint

I am doing some projects in SharePoint 2013 and I saw some blogs about deleting a site from IIS, why is not recommended not to delete sites from IIS ?

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint still assumes the site exists and even may not work properly even when we recreate them later. This what I see when I walk through the process.